# Powershell Job Step in SQL Error

Tags: sql-server, csv, powershell, sql-job

I'm new to PowerShell and still early in SQL Server, but I'm trying to write a PowerShell step for a SQL Agent job that looks at a CSV file that contains names of .sql files.

It should then look at a different directory and if the names from the CSV file exist in that directory it should open the .sql file and execute the function inside.

I'm getting an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String to type System.Type

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$excelFile = "C:/ExcelTest/Test.csv"
$functionDirectory = "some directory"

$excel_Array = (Get-Content $excelFile)[0].split(",")

foreach ($sqlName in $excel_Array) 
{
    if($sqlName::exists($functionDirectory + "/" + $sqlName) -ne $true) 
    {
        invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $functionDirectory + "/" + $sqlName -serverinstance "serverinstance" -database "database"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$sqlName::exists()` supposed to be doing? `$sqlName` is a string, and strings don't have an `exists` member

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the CSV file? It would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Eris
DS_ESR_Day.sql,

DS_ESR_PC_Month.sql,

DS_GRgrtPEI_CP_Day.sql,

DS_GRgrtPEI_Day.sql,

I can't format properly, but after each comma it goes to a new line.

Comment: @Eris is there any other info I can provide to help?  I've been tweaking with it for a while and get the same error.

Comment: @Eris Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 1):

If understand the question correctly, you need to use `Test-Path` not `::exists`

```
$excelFile = "C:/ExcelTest/Test.csv"
$functionDirectory = "some directory"

Import-Csv $excelFile | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $filename = $functionDirectory + '\' + $_[0]
        if (Test-Path $filename) {
            invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $filename -serverinstance "serverinstance" -database "database"
        }
    }
```

Comment: The goal is for the powershell to look at each line of the csv (each line is a sql file name like "Functionx.sql") and if that sql file exists in the $functionDirectory it opens the .sql file from $functionDirectory and runs the contents.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Ok, your code implied that all the filenames were on the first line of the file. I've updated the code to use Import-CSV instead

Comment: Getting an error "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid.  Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again".

Full code I'm running.

$excelFile = "C:\ExcelTest\Test.csv"
$functionDirectory = "C:\ActionMessages"

Import-Csv $excelFile | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $filename = $functionDirectory + '\' + $_[0]
        if (Test-Path $filename) {
            invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $filename -serverinstance "" -database ""
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust a few things in your script to properly handle a CSV and then utilize built-in cmdlet for testing the path of a given file.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
$functionDirectory = "C:\temp\PowerShell_Testing2"
$excelFile = Import-Csv "C:\temp\PowerShell_Testing\SQLFileList.csv"

foreach ($e in $excelFile) {
    $fileonly = Split-Path $e.SQLFile -Leaf
    $fdFile = $functionDirectory + "\" + $fileonly
    if (Test-Path $fdFile) {
        Write-Host "Found File $fdFile"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MANATARMS\SQL12" -InputFile $fdFile -Database master
    }
}
```

In my setup there is only one file that just runs:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM sys.databases
```

[image]

If your CSV contains say a ServerName, and then SQLFile you can adjust your script to also pull the `ServerInstance` value like this:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
$functionDirectory = "C:\temp\PowerShell_Testing2"
$excelFile = Import-Csv "C:\temp\PowerShell_Testing\SQLFileList.csv"

foreach ($e in $excelFile) {
    $fileonly = Split-Path $e.SQLFile -Leaf
    $fdFile = $functionDirectory + "\" + $fileonly
    if (Test-Path $fdFile) {
        Write-Host "Found File $fdFile"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $e.ServerName -InputFile $fdFile -Database master
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the Database argument on the `Invoke-SqlCmd`

Comment: @Shawn Tried your method from your first example as the csv's don't contain a server name and it results in failure with the invoke sql line "is missing a terminator".

Comment: That deals with the code in your files that you are trying to execute, you did not provide any examples.

Comment: @ShawnMelton It is not an issue with the sql in the files as the sql runs perfectly outside of your powershell example.  Even when invoking from ps the sql is still fine.

Comment: I would review the code you copy/pasted from my example to ensure the `dash` is correct in your version of the script and it was not replaced with another character.